# Dynamic Model Creation with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, etl

I'm working on an ETL tool recently, which, once given two connection strings, reads data from the first database, do transformations and persists them to the second database.

I'm using Spring Data JPA, but I'm stuck in a certain point:

My problem is that, when I connect to the first database, I must convert them into Java objects. In a simple project this is done by model classes annotated by `Entity`. But in this process the runtime environment doesn't know what tables it will encounter. For example, it is impossible to know if the database consists an `Actor` or `Movies` table -or both- and within those tables, the columns and their types will remain unknown.

I must do it in a generic way, but at the moment I can't even create corresponding Model classes. Is there a way of inferring tables and table structures just using `Spring Data JPA`?

P.s. I am trying to keep things simple and will go for `Spring JDBC` if I can't find a solution.

Comment: Not that I know of, JPA is exactly solving the porblem of ORM mapping. If you can't give it the Enity classes it won't generate ones itself (even if it did, how would one even know how to call methods on these magic classes?). Jdbc templates may ease using jdbc a bit. But I think you're going to have to poke at the `resultSet.getMetaData` to get anywhere